# Declaring a case list to be used in more than one place

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, select-case

I have the following code in my page which works fine although the number of cases is much much bigger. I need to use exactly the same list of cases in other selects but I don't want to have exactly the same code duplicate all over the place.

I have this:

```
   Select Case Request.Cookies("LatestRefer").Value
        Case "EZ12"
            freeCallNumber = "0800 111 1111"
        Case "EW56"
            freeCallNumber = "0800 222 2222"
        Case "AT34"
            freeCallNumber = "0800 333 3333"
        Case Else
                freeCallNumber = "0800 444 4444"
    End Select
```

I ideally want something like this

```
Select Case Request.Cookies("cookie1").Value
            myGlobalListOfCases()
        End Select

Select Case Request.Cookies("cookie2").Value
                myGlobalListOfCases()
            End Select

Select Case Request.Cookies("cookie3").Value
                    myGlobalListOfCases()
                End Select
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
Private Function getFreeCallNumber(ByVal value As String) As String
        Select Case value
            Case "EZ12"
                Return "0800 111 1111"
            Case Else
                Return "0800 222 2222"
        End Select
    End Function
```

And in the page_load:

```
If Not Request.Cookies("cookie1") is Nothing Then
    freeCallnumber = Me.getFreeCallNumber(Request.Cookies("cookie1").Value)
        Else
  freeCallnumber = Me.getFreeCallNumber(Request.Cookies("cookie2").Value)
        End If
```

This kind of works but there's a slight problem. I have to load the page twice for the phone number to change (or the phone number appears as it should have done on the previous load). Hope this makes sense... it's fairly odd behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you get this issue if you set (send) the cookies in the same page request? Or maybe it's a viewstate/databind issue, depending on what you do with the phone number. Try to debug the page or just write in to the response stream to see when it fetches the date. I.e. Response.Write("Number = " + freeCallNumber);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method:

```
private string getFreeCallNumber(string value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case "EZ12":
            return "0800 111 1111";
        case "EW56":
            return "0800 222 2222";
        // TODO: Add more switch cases here.
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

When calling it:

```
string freeCallnumber = this.getFreeCallNumber(Request.Cookies["cookie1"].Value));
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(freeCallNumber))
{
     // other logic
}
```

My guess that it's like this in VB.net:

```
Private Function getFreeCallNumber(value as String) as String
    Select Case value
        Case "EZ12"
            return "0800 111 1111"
        Case "EW56"
            return "0800 222 2222"
        ' TODO: Add more switch cases here.
        Case Else
            return Nothing
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Any idea how to get this working in VB?? I've had a good try but failed!

Comment: See if it's correct, the code I added. I haven't worked with VB.net before.

Comment: You got the same code as me, and with a bit of fiddling I've kind of got it working, but there's some odd behaviour... see the edits to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)
Note: is is serializable :-Q